# Illustrator: Transforming group of paths/compound paths results in different larger version

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I have a logo which I want to scale to a larger size.

I started by setting up my artboard to the size I wanted it, then I grouped all the logo paths/objects which are in one layer and opened the transform window to input the desired size with constrain proportions on.

Unfortunately this hasn't worked as expected, and there are gaps in the artwork, I think where things were overlapping and now aren't, or the rules for the compound paths in the artwork have rendered the logo differently at this bigger size.

I didn't create the artwork, so I am wondering how this might work? Or if I am going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before scaling, make certain `Scale Strokes & Effects` **is checked** in the preferences or on the Transform Panel.

Chances are when you scaled, some items retained their original size, which caused the gaps.

Beyond that.. sample images would be needed.